# How Can I Resize this Window?

Tags: resize

[image: screenshot of long window]

This window is too long for me to see the options at the bottom.  How can i resize it?
16.10 w/ Unity, btw.

Comment: Can you drag it against the top bar so it fills your whole screen or not?

Comment: Alt+drag anywhere on the window.

Comment: Thank you, but no, It won't go to fullscreen.  the window disappeared when i hit ESC, now the file transfer seems to be halted.  I tried deleting the folder and got an error, "There was an error getting information about the files in the folder "[gobbledygook]."

Comment: Try pressing alt+space and selecting _Resize_. Move your mouse to the bottom of the screen, press left mouse button to apply the size, then drag your box to the top of your screen, and repeat until it has shrunk to your desired size.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, click anywhere on the window and then drag it wherever you want..